# How to get the actual type in value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to reuse the thing just typed in an input. But there is 'always' a delay of one letter.

I must be missing something but I dont understand Why am I not getting the value I just typed in ?

Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/c9zutks9/

This is the code :

```
$('#cleaningFeed').keypress(function(){
    $('.res').html($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: have you tried binding to the `keyup` event in stead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keyup()` instead:

```
$('#cleaningFeed').keyup(function(){
    $('.res').html($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: What the heck --' How does that make even sense... :( anyway that's the answer thank you. Im going to read right away the documentation.